# Questions about the Fourier expansion of $e^{iz\cot(x)}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, special-functions, fourier-series

By analogy with [Jacobi–Anger expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion), one expects that $e^{iz\cot(x)}$ has a Fourier expansion of the form :
$$e^{iz\cot(\theta)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\Lambda_{n}(z)e^{in\theta}$$
$\Lambda_{n}(z)$ is given by:
$$\Lambda_{n}(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}e^{iz\cot(\theta)-in\theta}d\theta$$
A simple calculation yields:
$$\Lambda_{n}(z)=\frac{2}{n\pi}\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2} \right )\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{m}}{m!}\text{F}_{1}\left(-\frac{n}{2};-m,m;1-\frac{n}{2};1,-1 \right )$$

Where $\text{F}_{1}(\alpha;\beta,\beta^{'};\gamma;x,y)$ is the [Appell Hypergeometric Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html). Now, i have two questions:

1-For a purely imaginary $z$,$\;\;$ $e^{iz\cot(\theta)}$ has essential singularities at $\theta=\pm n\pi$, how is that reflected in the Fourier expansion !?

2-Can we express the infinite sum in terms of other special functions!?

Comment: This is pretty specialized, are you willing to share some background material? Why are we/you looking at this?

Answer (score 0):

use this
$$e^{z \cot ^2(x)}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } 2 (-1)^n \epsilon _n e^{\frac{1}{2} z \csc ^2(x)} \cos \left(2 n \sin ^{-1}(\cos (x))\right) I_n\left(\frac{1}{2} z \csc ^2(x)\right)$$

Comment: What is $\epsilon_n$?